# Can an ASP.NET MVC Area display its own set of error pages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, custom-errors

I've been consolidating some of my web apps into one main ASP.NET MVC project; assigning some of them to separate Areas, so that they can be accessed via subdomains.

Using this (quite helpful) resource (https://dusted.codes/demystifying-aspnet-mvc-5-error-pages-and-error-logging), I've set up `customErrors` and `httpErrors` in the `Web.config`, so that custom error pages are displayed. Works well.

I'll use different layout/styling per Area/subdomain, so I'm wondering:
*How can I get an Area to display its own set of error pages?*

With the current setup, all the subdomains will display the main set of custom errors that are added to the `customErrors` and `httpErrors` sections (403.html, 404.html, et cetera); but I'd prefer tailored error pages for some subdomains. (If one of the areas is exclusively handled by a separate domain altogether, for example, it won't be practical to serve the regular error pages.)

**Update:**
Here is the scenario, with code, as requested. Thanks to Ben Foster, who offered good guidance here: http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages[2](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages). I've put the code for customErrors, but not the corresponding httpErrors... left it out for brevity.

```
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/500.aspx">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.aspx" />
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/500.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>

  <location path="MyArea1">
    <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/Areas/MyArea1/500.aspx">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Areas/MyArea1/404.aspx" />
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Areas/MyArea1/500.aspx" />
      </customErrors>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="MyArea2">
    <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/Areas/MyArea2/500.aspx">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Areas/MyArea2/404.aspx" />
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Areas/MyArea2/500.aspx" />
      </customErrors>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

The above code works well:

- If I navigate to "example.com/does/not/exist", I get the
  expected error page at `~/404.aspx`.
- If I navigate to "example.com/MyArea1/does/not/exist", I will
  get the custom error page at `~/Areas/MyArea1/404.aspx`.

The challenge:

Now I'd like an Area (MyArea2) to be served by a totally separate domain (e.g. exampleOnMyOtherDomain.com), using `HostDomainConstraint` (as recommended by @TetsuyaYamamoto, in a comment below). A link that would have been accessible via "example.com/MyArea2/validlink" will now be accessed this way: "exampleOnMyOtherDomain.com/validlink".

Now, if I try "exampleOnMyOtherDomain.com/does/not/exist", I'll be served the top-level 404 (`~/404.aspx`). This is probably because "MyArea2" is not in the path anymore, so the location with the path "MyArea2" will not be picked up.

How can I get the Area (MyArea2) to serve its own error pages?

Comment: Probably location settings may help, see the reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178692.aspx. It can contains different content inside `<system.web>` element on each location, allowing `customErrors` and `httpErrors` to be set for different area by specifying area relative path.

Comment: Thanks @TetsuyaYamamoto; this was a pretty useful comment. I tried the `location` element, and when my Areas are a subpath of my main domain (e.g. http://example.com/MyArea), the `location` element works quite fine (`path="MyArea"`)! But here's the problem: When my Area is served up by a separate domain altogether, I can't use the same strategy (e.g. http://myotherexample.net).

Comment: Thanks @TetsuyaYamamoto; edited the question.

Comment: After looking to your web.config area setting, I assume you can use `Application_Error` to handle errors from myotherexample.net to `MyArea2` using `Request.Url.Host`. Additionally, you may set `MapRoute` to handle `MyArea2` as part of redirect area path, followed by IIS URL rewriting module as there: http://www.iis.net/expand/URLRewrite.

Comment: I've added an answer @TetsuyaYamamoto; pleas share your thoughts on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on some research, and helpful pointers from @TetsuyaYamamoto, I've employed the strategy below.

I'm handling the "Application_Error" event in `Global.asax`, using the following code:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string hostName = Request.Headers["host"].Split(':')[0];
    if (hostName.Contains("exampleOnMyOtherDomain"))
    {
        Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
        Response.Clear();
        HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        switch (httpException.GetHttpCode())
        {
            case 404:
                Response.StatusCode = 404;
                Server.Transfer("~/Errors/MyArea2_404.htm");
                break;
            case 500:
            default:
                Response.StatusCode = 500;
                Server.Transfer("~/Errors/MyArea2_500.htm");
                break;
        }
        Server.ClearError();
    }
}
```

Points to note:

- `hostName.Contains("exampleOnMyOtherDomain")` should compare the Host name with the Area I'm interested in handling. I'll add `else...if` statements for other Areas;
- `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true` should prevent IIS from attempting to handle the error;
- `Response.StatusCode` sets the status code appropriately ('404', '500'...);
- `Server.Transfer()` reads in a file that I'd like to display as the error page;
- `Server.ClearError()` should signal that the error has already been handled.

I want `customErrors`/`httpErrors` to continue handling regular errors. When execution passes through the `Application_Error` block without being handled (i.e. `Server.ClearError()` isn't called), `customErrors`/`httpErrors` will handle the error.

It seems that this is a decent strategy for handling errors for Areas that are served by a different domain.

Comment: IMHO this strategy was able to fulfill the separated domain handling for custom error pages, however you need to watch that  `TrySkipIisCustomErrors` was properly working. If the redirection to area error page won't work, check that `<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="PassThrough" />` is in place if IIS has been set to integrated mode, see this reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690576(v=vs.90).aspx.

Comment: Will do. Thanks @TetsuyaYamamoto, for all your help!

Comment: I have similar problem, I try to set different custom 404 pages for each areas? I have this in my web.config httpErrors
<error statusCode="404" path="/Error/NotFound/" responseMode="ExecuteURL" /> 
This routes main 404 page, but I try to show different 404 page if route has an area myhost/area/notfound/route should show myhost/myArea/Error/NotFound.
Should I ask a new question, if not how should I modify this solution?